# Use JQuery selector on the result of a selection?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

First, let's say I am selecting a bunch of TD Elements with:

```
var htmlRows = $( ".contentRow" );
```

I then do some searching and find that one of the nodes has something I need.

```
htmlRows.each( function(index, htmlRow){/*insert something to test here*/});
```

If my test is positive, i then need to find some tr node within that specific TD node, let's say with the id 'inputText'.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Show your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML in your question, or HTML that recreates your problem, and explain which element you want to retrieve (and on what basis). You shouldn't - typically - have `<tr>` elements inside of a `<td>`, as the `<td>` element should be a child of the `<tr>`. Unless you have nested `<table>` elements?

Comment: And, in any case, whenever you are looking for an element with a certain ID you can do that in an _absolute_ way, as IDs need to be _unique_ on a page.